# how to detect changes from one input to another input in the same component

Tags: angular

I need what I write in the internal filing input to be automatically reflected in work mission

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="mision.radicadoInterno" #radicadoInterno id="radicadoInterno">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="mision.misionTrabajo"  #misionTrabajo id="misionTrabajo">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: please clariy your question. Im getting only half of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use change or keydown or keyup or keypress events for your requirement.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="mision.radicadoInterno" #radicadoInterno (keydown)="updatemisionTrabajo($event)" id="radicadoInterno">
</mat-form-field>

updatemisionTrabajo(event) {
   this.mision.misionTrabajo = event.target.value;
}
```